# Send sendtextmessage via ts3 api

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

I have a problem. I have the following code:

```
import ts3
import time
with ts3.query.TS3Connection("185.201.114.62") as ts3conn:

    ts3conn.login(client_login_name="serveradmin", client_login_password="password")
    ts3conn.use(sid=1)
    ts3conn.send_keepalive()

    for client in ts3conn.clientlist():
        for cm in ts3conn.clientgetuidfromclid(clid=client["clid"]):
            #print(cm["cluid"])
            ts3conn.sendtextmessage(targetmode=1, target=cm["cluid"], msg="test")
```

And if I execute the code I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/kacpe/PycharmProjects/ts3bot/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    ts3conn.sendtextmessage(targetmode=1, target=cm["cluid"], msg="test")
  File "C:\Users\kacpe\.virtualenvs\ts3bot\lib\site-packages\ts3\commands.py", line 2909, in sendtextmessage
    return self._return_proxy("sendtextmessage", cparams, uparams, options)
  File "C:\Users\kacpe\.virtualenvs\ts3bot\lib\site-packages\ts3\query.py", line 469, in _return_proxy
    self, command, common_parameters, unique_parameters, options)
  File "C:\Users\kacpe\.virtualenvs\ts3bot\lib\site-packages\ts3\query.py", line 446, in send
    return self._wait_for_resp(timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Users\kacpe\.virtualenvs\ts3bot\lib\site-packages\ts3\query.py", line 383, in _wait_for_resp
    raise TS3QueryError(resp)
ts3.query.TS3QueryError: error id 1540: convert error
```

If I set targetmode to 2 (send message to channel) the code works, normal sending.

Comment: At which row do you get it, try to post the full traceback instead of just one line. But it's probably safe to assume it's `sendtextmessage` that's causing this?

Comment: Yes, error is in a 12 line, I don't know why. I write below full traceback.12 line is a ts3conn.sendtextmessage